# React Native: "Unrecognized font family" error disappears when I click font file in Xcode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, google-font-api, custom-font

In my React Native app I'm getting the error "Unrecognized font family: 'Raleway-Regular'". I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@kswanie21/custom-fonts-in-react-native-tutorial-for-ios-android-76ceeaa0eb78) to add my fonts, and in the "Optional step" section where you log all your attached fonts to the console, it includes all of them except `Raleway-Regular`.

However, the strange thing though is that when the app is sitting there in the emulator with the error screen, if I click any one of the font files in my `Fonts` folder in my project in Xcode, the error screen in my emulator disappears. Once I load any other screen, the error message reappears, and if I click one of the font files in Xcode, it disappears again. Note that when I click on one of the fonts, it does a hot reload of the screen I'm on in the emulator.

`Raleway-Regular.ttf` is in the `Fonts` folder in the root of my project and has the correct target membership, it's in my info.plist, it's in Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the parent folder path containing the Raleway-Regular.tff

```
"rnpm": {
   "assets": [
      "./Fonts/"
   ]
 }
```

Edit, please use this instead:

pls create this file: `react-native.config.js` with this content :

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./Fonts/'],
};
```

Comment: I think rnpm was deprecated as of reac-native@0.60, right?

Comment: yes, you are correct. with that, can you try this instead:
``
1. create a file called : react-native.config.js
2. add this in that file:

module.exports = {
  assets: ['./Fonts/'],
};
``